# when i select the contacts tab the tab bar is vanished

Tags: java, android, android-intent, tabs, tabview

i have four tabs in the tab bar when i select the contact tab from the tab bar  the tab bar is disappeared.i want to show the tab bar when i select the contact tab.
Here is code 
**TabActivity.java**

```
public class Tab_Activity extends TabActivity 
{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources obj_res = getResources();


        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


         TabSpec m_tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
         TabSpec m_tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");




         Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(this, Phone.class);
         Intent intent3 = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
         Intent intent4 = new Intent().setClass(this, Contact.class);


         m_tab4.setIndicator("Tab4");
         m_tab4=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("", obj_res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1)).setContent(intent3);



         m_tab5.setIndicator("Tab4");
         m_tab5=tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("", obj_res.getDrawable(R.drawable.pic3)).setContent(intent4);

         tabHost.addTab(m_tab2);
         tabHost.addTab(m_tab4);
         tabHost.addTab(m_tab5);


    }}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact extends Activity 
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.contact);

        Intent Contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Contacts.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        Contacts.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(Contacts, 1); 

}}
```

Comment: because you started another app with the intent ... you can not embed other app's activity inside your activity ...

Comment: selvin plz tel me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is your activity in which u can put how many tab you want to display.

```
    public class GuestListAdminActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Bride", "Groom", "Create Gueset List" };



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest_list_admin);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());



    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);      

    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

}

This is pager adapter which will show your all fragments.

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {





    switch (index) {
    case 0:


         return new BrideGuestList();

    case 1:

        return new GroomGuestList();
    case 2:

       return new NewGuestListActivity();

    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;


}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

And make your fragment activity like following

```
public class BrideGuestList extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bride_guest_list, container, false);

         return rootView;
```

}

Comment: this is not a solution that i wanted

Comment: then explain what you wanted.

Comment: The problem im facing is when i select the tab the activity is appear but the Tab bar is disappears. in contact class i start the new intent to access the phone contact.any one know without starting the new intent we can access the phone contact.or it is possible if i start new intent inthe contact class the bar is visibile.